# Opening a native app within a JFrame

Tags: java, desktop-application, native, jdic, solidworks

I have a fullscreen app that needs to open edrawings, is it at all possible to load edrawings within the Java app so that as soon as the user closes the drawing it will return to the fullscreen app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if the application is a / has a COM interface.

An example is [JExplorer](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexplorer/docs/JExplorer-PGuide.html), and it can generally done using 
[ComfyJ](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/comfyj/docs/ComfyJ-PGuide.html#Embedding_ActiveX_OLE_Components_into_Swing_Application) (which is not free).

I haven't done it personally though, so I don't know the requirements such a setup would have for your application.

Comment: I will take a look into these and see if it is worth it. Thanks.